# Portable check for library

Tags: powershell, gcc, msys2, dev-null

A project I am trying to compile has this command:

```
cc -xc++ -o/dev/null -lc++ -shared
```

However I am using PowerShell, which has no notion of `/dev/null`:

```
PS C:\> cc -xc++ -o/dev/null -lc++ -shared
C:/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../
x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot open output file /dev/null.exe: No such
file or directory
```

I tried using `-o$null`, but it just creates a file `$null.exe`. I also tried this:

```
PS C:\> cc -xc++ -o $null -lc++ -shared
cc.exe: fatal error: no input files
```

Is PowerShell able to handle this use case? Alternatively, it seems the purpose of the test is to just check if `libc++` exists. Is another way available to do that?

Comment: You can `test-path` to return a Boolean for a directory, and I believe the equivalent of `/dev/null` in PowerShell would be having `>> $null` at the end of a command that produces output. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Argument `-o/dev/null` would be passed verbatim by cmd, PowerShell, and any POSIX-compatible shell, so the premise of this question is flawed: this can't be PowerShell-specific. `/dev/null` (case-_sensitively_) is the null device on Unix-like platforms, whereas it is `NUL` (case-_insensitively_) on Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the issue is specific to GCC. If I [get Clang](//github.com/mstorsjo/llvm-mingw), the same command
works [with nul](//support.microsoft.com/help/110930):

```
cc -xc++ -onul -lc++ -shared
```

but if I try the same thing with GCC, I get this:

```
C:/msys2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../
x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: nul.exe: final close failed: file truncated
```

I have posted [bug 97574](//gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=97574).